# Split array in json into mutiple objects in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON object which contains array fields. Now I want o extract the array and split it into multiple objects.

JSON object:-

```
{'catalog_num': 5,
    'data_array': ['16.1', 
                   '76.1', 
                   '14.1', 
                   '14.1'
                  ]
}
```

Now I want the split this json array into multiple objects

```
   {'catalog_num': 5,
    'data_id': '16.1'},

 {'catalog_num': 5,
    'data_id': '76.1'},

   {'catalog_num': 5,
    'data_id': '14.1'},

   {'catalog_num': 5,
    'data_id': '14.1'},
```

Comment: you mean different dict variables according to elements in data_id?

Comment: That's not a JSON object, that's a Python dictionary.

Comment: Consider the answers if they solve your problem and upvote them

Comment: is not a JSON file, JSON requires double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please let me know if you have any other requirements

```py
data = {'catalog_num': 5,
    'data_array': ['16.1', 
                   '76.1', 
                   '14.1', 
                   '14.1'
                  ]
}

objects_list = []

for data in data["data_array"]:
    object = {
       'catalog_num': data['catalog_num'],
       'data_id': data
    }
    objects_list.append(object)

print(objects_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Sridhar's answer, you can do this with list comprehension with less code like this

```
data = {'catalog_num': 5,
        'data_array': ['16.1',
                       '76.1',
                       '14.1',
                       '14.1'
                       ]
        }


result = [{
    'catalog_num': data['catalog_num'],
    'data_id': data_id,
} for data_id in data['data_array']]
```

Comment: maybe it's too advanced to talk about list comprehensions for newbies. Just an opinion  :)

Comment: That is why I added it as an addition to your answer, your's is descriptive. He should know what options exist, I think.

Comment: Yeah nice job. see ya